# python REST server PUT does not update value

Tags: python, rest, get, put

I have python REST server running and i am trying to update a string via PUT method and after that use a GET method (different client) to retrieve said updated string. But the problem is that GET method gets the old string( in this case "0"). Which one of the methods might be wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests. jsonify

badpackets = "0"

@app.route('/badpkts/<string:badpackets>', methods=['PUT'])
def post_bad_packets(badpackets):
    badpackets = request.jsonify
    return jsonify(badpackets)
@app.route('/badpkts/', methods=['GET'])
def get_bad_packets():
    return jsonify(badpackets)
```

Comment: `def get_bad_packets:` is a syntax error.  This can't be your real code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Sorry, its missing () as i wrote the code from different computer that it runs so its just a typo. edited it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_bad_packets()` function only knows about the *global* variable named `badpackets`.  The variable of the same name inside the `post_bad_packets()` function is a *local* variable.

If you want to change the value of a global variable inside a function, use the `global` keyword.  I'd also recommend using a different name for the parameter to `post_bad_packets()`.

Comment: so i should use  `global badpackets = request.jsonify` ?

Comment: No, that's not the right syntax.  Check out a python tutorial on global variables.  Also, as I said, you'll want to change the name of the `badpackets` parameter, since it is shadowing the global variable of  the same name.

Comment: But is there any need for that parameter anymore? I thought i need to pass the badpackets in to the function to change it. But if i assign new global parameter then there is no need for it?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `request.json`, not `request.jsonify`?  There's a good reason not to type code in from memory; these silly mistakes make it much harder for people to help.

Comment: If you expect the bad packet to come from the json data, then you don't need it as an argument.  But if you expect it to come from the URL, as your `app.route` line says, then you do need it as an argument.  So, which is it?

Comment: Yes but if i assign `global badpackets` inside that function and change the route to '/badpkts/' there is no need for the parameter? Atleast it functions as supposed now..

Comment: From the json. I guess i got mixed up with all of this. But now it works. Thank you.